# Taxonomy of recommender system methodologies

Tags: recommender-system

There's tons of material online but yet I can't reconcile the different definitions for recommender system methodologies / strategies.

I think we can identify several axes:

- [*memory* vs *model* based;](http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/modelbased.html) *Model based* models do not need to store historical data such as user ratings or proxies (implicit data) such as purchase behavior, views, etc.
- *product based* vs [*collaborative filtering*](http://guidetodatamining.com/assets/guideChapters/DataMining-ch3.pdf), aka user-based filtering. *Collaborative filtering* relies on user preferences data (implicit or explicit - explicit when users explicitly provide ratings, likes, stars). *Product based* rely uniquely on product features.

*collaborative filtering* comprises [*item based*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372191/whats-difference-between-collaborative-filtering-item-based-recommendation-and), which is totally based on user-item rankings, and *content-based recommendation*, which exploits product features and user preferences (although [other](https://www.snet.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg220/courses/SS11/snet-project/recommender-systems_asanov.pdf) [sources](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0950705113001044/1-s2.0-S0950705113001044-main.pdf?_tid=99dd187a-473f-11e6-8d54-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1468225097_64f218616122bd940356a774d632f761) put content based filtering outside the family of collaborative filtering)

Is this correct? Anything (big) missing?

Comment: I'd suggest reading a survey such as [this one](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950705113001044).